# How to copy files that match elements on a list?

Tags: linux, bash, cp, selection, parsing

Imagine I have many files whose names are of the form `file#.tex`
9that is, `file1.tex`, `file2.tex`, ..., `file100.tex`). I need to copy only those files whose number `#` is in another file named `chosen.txt` whose content is, for example:

```
2
3
4
14
26
99
```

i.e., I would need to copy to a different directory only six files `file#.txt` whose number `#` is in the list above.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: What have you tried? A shell loop (`while read …`)? `xargs`? Anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```bsh
sed -E 's/.+/file&.tex/' chosen.txt | xargs echo cp -t /other/directory
```

If that emits a cp command that looks correct, remove "echo"